# Set element name same as RootElement attribute

Tags: c#, generics, xml-serialization

```
[XmlRootAttribute("ls")]
public class Request<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute("ver")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("hdr")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(class2), ElementName = "ChildClass")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot("ChildClass")]
public class class2
{
    [XmlElement("login")]
    public string Property1{ get; set; }

}
[XmlRoot("ChildClass3")]
public class class3
{
    [XmlElement("User")]
    public string Property1{ get; set; }

}
```

When `Request<class2>` is serialized , Element name is "Data". I want element Name to be "ChildClass". when `Request<class3>` is serialized , Element name should be "ChildClass3". 
How can i do that

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I put a comment after editing code. Where is it?

Comment: I don't know - I am unable to remove someone else's comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the element name must be known at compile time and so you can't try and use the Data objects XmlRoot or class name or similar as these aren't known at compile time.  You'll need to define every possible type that you could expect `Data` to be set to.  As follows:

```
[XmlRoot("ls")]
public class Request
{
    [XmlAttribute("ver")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ChildClass2",typeof(class2))]
    [XmlElement("ChildClass3",typeof(class3))]
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class class2
{
    [XmlElement("login")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class class3
{
    [XmlElement("User")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

}
```

The following two objects:

```
var exampleObject = new Request
{
    Version = "versionExample",
    Data = new class2 { Property1 = "property1Example" }
};

var exampleObject2 = new Request
{
    Version = "versionExample",
    Data = new class3 { Property1 = "property1Example" }
};
```

Then serialized to:

```
<ls ver="versionExample">
  <ChildClass2>
    <login>property1Example</login>
  </ChildClass2>
</ls>
<ls ver="versionExample">
  <ChildClass3>
    <User>property1Example</User>
  </ChildClass3>
</ls>
```

Comment: This is perfect. I want to point out that we can't have Data declared as Type T .It will fail with casting exception at runtime